# Pull private package from Github

Tags: docker, github

I've set a Github action to create and publish a Docker image into ghcr. I can see under my repository that the image is successfully created and even suggesting me a command to pull it:

`docker pull ghcr.io/username/appname:master`

But I believe since the repository is private this doesn't work as easy as it seems.

I've tried following command but not helping either:

```
docker login ghcr.io -u username --password-stdin | docker pull ghcr.io/username/appname:master

Error response from daemon: Get "https://ghcr.io/v2/": denied: denied
Error response from daemon: unauthorized
```

My end goal is to create a sort of run.sh file for the front-end developers to pull backend images and run them. All the answers I could find were about pulling the image with GITHUB_TOKEN in another actions but that's not the case.

I've also seen some answers saying I need a PAT to access ghcr, I've created one but couldn't find a way to use it in cmd.

Comment: What else have you tried to resolve the problem? What about https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-container-registry - it tells you how to use the token

Comment: @NicoHaase I've tried this one as well, first I get `Login succeeded` and right after that when I try to pull the image: `Error response from daemon: unauthorized`

Comment: @NicoHaase Ah wait the issue was about the access rights of the token itself. I feel so stupid...

Comment: Did you solve this eventually?

Comment: @vlio20 Yes I solved it, the issue was about the access rights of the token.

Answer (score 2):

First set an authentication using [developer settings](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) on the GitHub account. Follow steps for [container registry](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-container-registry)

```
$sudo echo $CR_PAT | docker login ghcr.io -u USERNAME --password-stdin
> Login Succeeded
```

where USERNAME is your GitHub login account username, $CR_PAT  is generated token

use `$sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock`; if you get docker socket permission issue